# Mysql query runs too long on OR condition

Tags: mysql

Here is query what take 12 seconds

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT `t`.* FROM `wp_pods_bars` AS `t` 
LEFT JOIN `wp_podsrel` AS `rel_city` ON 
    ( `rel_city`.`field_id` = 13918 AND `rel_city`.`item_id` = `t`.`id` ) OR 
    ( `rel_city`.`related_field_id` = 13918 AND `rel_city`.`related_item_id` = `t`.`id` )
```

if I do

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT `t`.* FROM `wp_pods_bars` AS `t` 
LEFT JOIN `wp_podsrel` AS `rel_city` ON 
    ( `rel_city`.`field_id` = 13918 AND `rel_city`.`item_id` = `t`.`id` )
```

or

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT `t`.* FROM `wp_pods_bars` AS `t` 
LEFT JOIN `wp_podsrel` AS `rel_city` ON 
    ( `rel_city`.`related_field_id` = 13918 AND `rel_city`.`related_item_id` = `t`.`id` )
```

each query runs 0,09 seconds. Why so and how to fix this?

EDIT:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT `t`.* FROM `wp_pods_bars` AS `t` 
LEFT JOIN `wp_podsrel` AS `rel_city` ON 
    ( `rel_city`.`related_field_id` = 13918 AND `rel_city`.`related_item_id` = `t`.`id` )
```

result

```
id,select_type,table,type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref,rows,Extra
1,SIMPLE,t,ALL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1340,Using temporary
1,SIMPLE,rel_city,ref,rel_field_rel_item_idx,rel_field_item_idx,rel_field_rel_item_idx,14,const,barchick.t.id,1,Using index; Distinct
```

second

```
EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT `t`.* FROM `wp_pods_bars` AS `t` 
LEFT JOIN `wp_podsrel` AS `rel_city` ON 
( `rel_city`.`related_field_id` = 13918 AND `rel_city`.`related_item_id` = `t`.`id` )
```

result

```
id,select_type,table,type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref,rows,Extra
1,SIMPLE,t,ALL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1340,Using temporary
1,SIMPLE,rel_city,ref,rel_field_rel_item_idx,rel_field_item_idx,rel_field_rel_item_idx,14,const,barchick.t.id,1,Using index; Distinct
```

Comment: do you have index on `t.id` and `rel_city.related_item_id`?

Comment: Prepend `EXPLAIN` to each of the queries, and paste the results.

Comment: Does the query you have produce different results than this one:? `SELECT t.* FROM wp_pods_bars AS t;`

Comment: @ypercube, yes both queries returns the same results

Comment: So, use this one. The `LEFT` join you have is redundant as you don't use the right table for anything in the results :)

Comment: @ypercube its a dumb wordpress, it generates this query automatically. So I have to either fix mysql or write query manually what take a few hours to rewrite a whole section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LEFT` join you have is redundant as you don't use the right table for anything in the results. And any duplicate rows produced by the join are removed by the `DISTINCT`.

So your query is equivalent to this one which fetches all rows from the table (as long as there is a primary or unique key in `wp_pods_bars`):

```
SELECT t.* FROM wp_pods_bars AS t ;
```

No `DISTINCT`, no `JOIN`, no `OR`.

---

There is a feature in MariaDB, called **[Table Elimination](https://kb.askmonty.org/en/table-elimination/)** (see also in **[Sergey Petrunia's blog](http://s.petrunia.net/blog/?p=58)** for an explanation) that may work as your wish and eliminate the join but of course switching from MySQL to MariaDB may not be an available option for you.